# Pytest unittest function doesn't return any value

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

Could you please help me understand issue with below unittest?
Here's my function for which i am writing unittest.

```py
def running_config_from_database(device):
    try:
        data = databaseproxy(cluster='https://xxx.xxxx.xxx.net')
        datadb = 'test'
        query = f'''fGetrunningconfigData('{device}')
         '''
        raw_data = data.execute_query(datadb, query)
        # pdb.set_trace()
        for items in raw_data.fetchall():
            config = items['Config'].split('\r\n')
        for index, line in enumerate(config):
            if '$PASS$' in line:
                if line.startswith('set groups ospf_test'):
                    config_line = line.replace('$PASS$', get_auth('ospf'))
                    config[index] = config_line
                elif line.startswith('set groups rip_test'):
                    config_line = line.replace('$PASS$', get_auth('rsvp'))
                    config[index] = config_line
        config = config + overload_config
        return True, '\r\n'.join(config)
    except Exception as e:
        return False, f'Failed to get the running config from database, error: {e}'
```

Here's my unittest for this function:

```
@patch("scripts.test.overload_config")
@patch("scripts.test.get_auth")
@patch("scripts.test.databaseproxy.execute_query")
def test_running_config_from_database(self, mock_data, mock_cred, mock_overload):
    ret = MagicMock()
    ret.fetchall.return_value = [{'Hostname': 'devA', 'Config': 'set groups ospf_test secret $PASS$\r\n'}]
    mock_data.return_value = ret
    mock_cred.return_value = 'xyz'
    mock_overload = ['sample_overload_config1', 'sample_overload_config2']
    expected = ['set groups ospf_test secret xyz', '']
    out = expected + mock_overload
    data = '\r\n'.join(out) 
    status, out1 = tests.test_scripts.running_config_from_database('devA')
    assert status and out1 == data
```

When I run this unittest to test the function, I get the below assertion error - looks like the function doesn't return any value.

```
@patch("scripts.test.overload_config")
@patch("scripts.test.get_auth")
@patch("scripts.test.databaseproxy.execute_query")
def test_running_config_from_database(self, mock_data, mock_cred, mock_overload):
        ret = MagicMock()
        ret.fetchall.return_value = [{'Hostname': 'devA', 'Config': 'set groups ospf_test secret $PASS$\r\n'}]
        mock_data.return_value = ret
        mock_cred.return_value = 'xyz'
        mock_overload = ['sample_overload_config1', 'sample_overload_config2']
        expected = ['set groups ospf_test secret xyz', '']
        out = expected + mock_overload
        data = '\r\n'.join(out) 
        status, out1 = tests.test_scripts.running_config_from_database('devA')
>       assert status and out1 == data
E       AssertionError: assert (True and '' == 'set groups d...rload_config2'
E         + set groups ospf_test secret xyz
E         + 
E         + sample_overload_config1
E         + sample_overload_config2)
tests/test_scripts.py:80: AssertionError
```

I edited my function to reduce the complexity but it still doesn't work. not sure why.

```
Main Function:
```

==============

```
def running_config_from_database(device):
    try:
        pdb.set_trace()
        config = running_config_database(device)
        for index, line in enumerate(config):
            if '$PASS$' in line:
                if line.startswith('set groups ospf_test'):
                    config_line = line.replace('$PASS$', get_cred('ospf'))
                    config[index] = config_line
        config = config + overload_config
        return True, '\r\n'.join(config)
    except Exception as e:
        return False, f'Failed to get the running config from Database, error: {e}'
```

UnitTest Result for above Function:

```
=========================================================================================================== FAILURES ============================================================================================================
________________________________________________________________________________________________ test_running_config_from_database _________________________________________________________________________________________________

mock_cred = <MagicMock name='get_cred' id='140210277622336'>, mock_overload = ['sample_overload_config1', 'sample_overload_config2'], mock_running_config = <MagicMock name='running_config_database' id='140210277652128'>

    @patch("test.test1.scripts.running_config_database")
    @patch("test.test1.scripts.overload_config")
    @patch("test.test1.scripts.get_cred")
    def test_running_config_from_database(mock_cred, mock_overload, mock_running_config):
        mock_running_config.return_value = ['set groups ospf_test secret $PASS$', '']
        mock_cred.return_value = 'xyz'
        mock_overload = ['sample_overload_config1', 'sample_overload_config2']
        expected = ['set groups ospf_test secret xyz', '']
        out = expected + mock_overload
        data = '\r\n'.join(out)
        status, out1 = test.test1.scripts.test_running_config_from_database('devA')
>       assert status and out1 == data
E       AssertionError: assert (True and '' == 'set groups d...rload_config2'
E         + set groups ospf_test secret xyz
E         + 
E         + sample_overload_config1
E         + sample_overload_config2)

validation_tests/test_scripts.py:152: AssertionError
================================================================================================== 1 failed, 6 passed in 4.79s ==================================================================================================
```

Comment: You mock `'scripts.test.xxx'`, but call `tests.test_scripts.running_config_from_database`. Shouldn't you also mock `tests.test_scripts.xxx`?

Comment: Also, you just re-assign `mock_overload`, so the mock is not used - provided it is a list, you shall probably do `mock_overload[:] = [...]` instead. Apart from these, it looks ok to me.

Comment: do you notice that the complexity of writing this test is increasing with your function? perhaps it is time to think about breaking your function down in to smaller pieces so that the function does just one thing and makes it easer to test...

Comment: @MrBeanBremen, thanks for your comment. I had to edit the function/unittest before pasting the output here and that's the reason do you see the difference. I have mocked all the dependencies.

Comment: @gold_cy, yeah, i am working on that but was wondering, what did i do wrong

Comment: Ok, did you fix the `mock_overload` setting then, and it still doesn't work?

Comment: @MrBeanBremen, not sure if i understood how i re-assign mock_overload but it's working fine in similar way for other UT

Comment: Well, it cannot work this way, because you don't change the used mock this way. And I wrote how to do it correctly: you have to use `mock_overload[:] = ['sample_overload_config1', ...]` instead - this will _change_ the mock content instead of just replacing the object.

Comment: I see, It worked when i edited the config as you said. Thank you very much @MrBeanBremen.
`validation_tests/scripts.py::test_running_config_database PASSED                                                                                                                                      [ 85%]
validation_tests/scripts.py::test_running_config_from_database PASSED                                                                                                                                 [100%]`

Comment: @MrBeanBremen, not sure how can i mark your comment as answer. else.
let me post the answer so that it can help others if they face similar issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is the assignment to `mock_overload`. If you want to adapt your mocked object you have to make sure that the object itself is changed. If you just assign another object (in this case, a list), your variable now points to the list object, while the original `mock_overload` is no longer referenced (and is not changed). So instead of writing:

```py
mock_overload = ['sample_overload_config1', 'sample_overload_config2']
```

you can for example write

```py
mock_overload[:] = ['sample_overload_config1', 'sample_overload_config2']
```

For clarification, here is a simplified version of the original code:

```
>>> mock_overload = []
>>> id(mock_overload)
1477793866440
>>> mock_overload = [5, 6]
>>> id(mock_overload)
1477791015560  <- changed id, no longer pointing to the mock
```

Now the same with the fixed code:

```
>>> mock_overload = []
>>> id(mock_overload)
140732764763024
>>> mock_overload[:] = [5, 6]
>>> id(mock_overload)
140732764763024  <- unchanged id, still points to the mock
```

Note that `mock_overload[:] = [5, 6]` is basically a shortcut for:

```py
mock_object.clear()
mock_object.extend([5, 6])
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer is already provided in comment section by @MrBean Bremen. here's the UT after making changes suggested.

```
@patch("scripts.test.overload_config")
@patch("scripts.test.get_auth")
@patch("scripts.test.databaseproxy.execute_query")
def test_running_config_from_database(self, mock_data, mock_cred, mock_overload):
    ret = MagicMock()
    ret.fetchall.return_value = [{'Hostname': 'devA', 'Config': 'set groups ospf_test secret $PASS$\r\n'}]
    mock_data.return_value = ret
    mock_cred.return_value = 'xyz'
    ***mock_overload[:]*** = ['sample_overload_config1', 'sample_overload_config2']
    expected = ['set groups ospf_test secret xyz', '']
    out = expected + mock_overload
    data = '\r\n'.join(out) 
    status, out1 = tests.test_scripts.running_config_from_database('devA')
    assert status and out1 == data
```